# Shiro Plugin conflicting with Quartz framework in Grails

Tags: maven, grails, quartz-scheduler, grails-plugin, shiro

I have been working Quartz framework in my grails project with lib called quartz-all-1.7.3.

Now I need to install the shiro plugin to my project. So, whenever I am installing shiro plugin to my project its getting installed successfully..

But again whenever I am running my project again it's giving compilation error as follows :

```
  [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
  [groovyc] Compile error during compilation with javac.
  [groovyc] ....scheduler\quartz\framework\CustomJDBCDelegate.java:46: com.securonix.application.scheduler.quartz.framework.CustomJDBCDelegate is not abstract and does not override abstract method updateSchedulerState(java.sql.Connection,java.lang.String,long,java.lang.String) in org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.DriverDelegate
  [groovyc] public class CustomJDBCDelegate implements DriverDelegate, StdJDBCConstants {
  [groovyc]        ^
```

So after long look on shiro plugin I have found that it has some dependencies with plugins. In that one of the dependency is shiro-quartz-1.0.0-incubating.jar. So, now inside it's pom.xml file I have seen following line code :

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>quartz</groupId>
     <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

As per our line in pom.xml, there is no tag of version with quartz dependency, that means whenever shiro getting installed in my project, simultaneously it's extracting latest library of quartz i.e. 1.8.3 with maven.

And inside that `quartz 1.8.3` the method updateSchedulerState of class CustomJDBCDelegate has been changed from version `quarts 1.7.3`.

So now problem is I cannot change `quartz-all-1.7.3` in my existing project, and wanted to use Shiro plugin too in my project.

So there should be some resolution so that shiro should get `quartz-1.7.3` version rather than the latest one using maven.

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm getting this wrong, do you mean something like this?:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-incubating</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>quartz</groupId>
                <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

then `$ mvn dependency:tree`

[...]

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-quartz:jar:1.0.0-incubating:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:jar:1.0.0-incubating:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:1.7.3:compile
[INFO]    \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]       +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12:compile
[INFO]       +- logkit:logkit:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]       \- avalon-framework:avalon-framework:jar:4.1.3:compile
```